# Systemd starts emacs daemon without XAUTHORITY environment variable after upgrading to Fedora 37

Tags: fedora, systemd, emacs

### Problem

I am running Emacs daemon as a user service using Systemd, following the [documentation in EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#h5o-2). I configured it while using Fedora-36, and everything was working as expected. Once I upgraded to Fedora-37, `emacsclient -c` started failing with error `*ERROR*: Display :0 can't be opened`; the Emacs daemon also added `Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified` to the `systemctl --user status emacs.service` output.

### Temporary solution.

First I figured out that simply restarting the service using `systemctl --user restart emacs.service` fixed the problem until I reboot the machine again. But having to restart the service manually every time I start the machine defeated the point of starting it automatically using Systemd.

### Debugging attempt.

After some research on the topic, I figured out that the emacs daemon is not getting the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable when started automatically. Running `ps -C emacs eww` after a reboot, I can see that the following 14 environment variables are set.

```
HOME, LANG, LOGNAME, PATH, SHELL, SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID, USER, 
XDG_DATA_DIRS, XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS, 
NOTIFY_SOCKET, MANAGERPID, INVOCATION_ID, JOURNAL_STREAM
```

After restarting the service, I see 43 environment variables. Amount the 29 new variables, there is `DISPLAY`, `GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY`, `WAYLAND_DISPLAY`, and **`XAUTHORITY`**.

So one possibility is that Systemd is starting user services before these variables are available, which causes the problem. If this is the case, how can I fix it?

But I also found that I could just create a soft link named `.Xauthority` file in my home directory, which points to the actual one, and Emacs seems to work without these environment variables. So maybe these environment variables are not needed and what changed from fedora-36 to fedora-37 is not having the `.Xauthority` file in the home directory any more. If this is the case, how should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently ran into this issue after switching from Plasma X11 to Plasma Wayland on my F37 install.  The consensus I've seen from searching the web seems to be what you've found: `emacs.service` is being started before the graphical environment and `DISPLAY` variables are available.  I didn't have the `Authorization required` message you had though.

I started with moving the `emacs.service` file from `~/.config/systemd/user/default.target.wants` to `~/.config/systemd/user/graphical-session.target.wants`, but that didn't change anything.

Taking a hint from [How can I start systemd service units in order?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379363/how-can-i-start-systemd-service-units-in-order), I copied `/usr/lib/systemd/user/emacs.service` to `~/.config/systemd/user`, linked it into the `graphical-session.target.wants` folder and added the following lines to the `[Unit]` section

```
Requires=plasma-kwin_wayland.service
After=plasma-kwin_wayland.service
```

After rebooting and logging back in, I verified `emacs.service` was running, and was able to start up `emacsclient` as usual.

Comment: I did something similar. I copied `/usr/lib/systemd/user/emacs.service` to `~/.config/systemd/user/`, added your `Requires=` and `After=` lines under the `[Unit]` section, and changed the `WantedBy=` target under `[Install]` to `plasma-core.target`. I then ran `systemctl --user enable emacs` to automatically create the appropriate symlink.