# Can systemd start a user service after loading `.profile`?

Tags: systemd, path, emacs

I'm using systemd to start the Emacs daemon, as explained in the [Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#h5o-2).

I also use my `~/.profile` file to add my user-installed TeX Live installation to the `PATH` variable, so it contains the line

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
```

Apparently, the emacs daemon is started before that line is executed. `[M-x] getenv [RET] PATH` reveals that the texlive directory is not part of the `PATH` emacs is aware of.

Note that

```
systemctl --user show-environment
```

gives the correct path, so that executing

```
systemctl restart --user emacs
```

resolves the situation for the current session.

Is there a way to make systemd wait for the `.profile` file to be executed before starting a user service?

Comment: Back up - your problem is NOT getting systemd to deal with .profile, its that the PATH is not setup for systemd (which amongst other things isolates the environment of the programs it tuns from its own environment) - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347873/set-path-for-a-systemd-unit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set PATH for a systemd unit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/347873/set-path-for-a-systemd-unit)

Comment: @symcbean Not really. I dislike the idea of having to set the environment variable separately for every systemd unit that might want to use it. Ideally, there is a single config file that sets my user PATH for everything. I always thought `.profile` is that place.

Comment: Then use a different service manager than systemd (although the ones I'm familiar with are all the same in this regard).

Comment: Maybe some variant of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/728058/systemd-starts-emacs-daemon-without-xauthority-environment-variable-after-upgrad/ will help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way to set the environment for user services is described in [man
environment.d](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/environment.d.html).
Typically, you would create a file
`~/.config/environment.d/90texlive.conf`, for example, holding the line

```
PATH="$HOME/.local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
```

This file is parsed by systemd, so beware the syntax is limited, but it can
usually be made compatible with the shell, so you could `source` it from
your `.profile` if you do not want to repeat the line there.
Remember to do a `systemctl --user daemon-reload` when testing.

Note that systemd initialises the PATH to something that may not be as
extensive as what your shell normally gets, so you may want to have other
config lines or files too.

How does your `.profile` PATH eventually find its way into systemd's
environment? Possibly some part of the desktop startup does something like

```
systemctl --user import-environment
```

or

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd --all
```

Comment: You can't really just source an environment.d conf because you can't use `export` in it, while you need that keyword in shell. A `read` loop should do though.

Comment: Yeah that works. I had to use `991-path.conf` though, because for some reason, `/etc/environment` is linked to `/usr/lib/environment.d/99-environment.conf`, so that my own config got overwritten when first trying this.

Comment: @TomYan you are right. Some variables like PATH are usually already marked for export anyway, and just giving them a new value through `source` will work in those particular circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for `.profile` to be executed is not going to help in your problem, because the user services are not child processes of the shell that executes `~/.profile`, and so **cannot inherit any environment variable settings from it**.

If you want a customized `$PATH` for your `emacs.service`, you will have to do it in the service file (or an override file), probably with an `Environment=` option in the `[Service]` section. Note that environment variable expansion will not be performed for the `Environment=` option, so you won't be able to use `$HOME` or `$PATH`, but you can use `%h` to refer to the user's home directory.

So, the `Environment=` line you'd need might be something like this:

```
Environment="PATH=%h/.local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux:%h/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
```

Comment: Your first sentence is not entirely correct: If I restart the service from my command line, it does indeed inherit the environment variables set in `.profile`. Interestingly, the same happens when I log out and log in again.

Comment: @red_trumpet "If I restart the service from my command line" how do you do that restarting, specifically?

Comment: @MarcusMüller As written in my post, using `systemctl restart --user emacs`. Also, `systemctl --user show-environment` seems to know the correct `PATH`.